# Punctuation in sarcastic question with suggested answer?

Tags: punctuation, sarcasm

How do you correctly format a sarcastic question that includes a suggested answer?

Like...

> Where did you get your license: the back of a cereal box?

Is that correct? It seems wrong to make it two independent sentences, both ending with question marks, if the suggested answer is a run-on part of the same sarcastic question.

Comment: you want to *say* that or *write?*

Comment: what about putting an *em-dash* after the first part of the question?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There doesn't seem to be a standard way to do this. Looking through Google books, I found:

- a dash: *“Where did you get your license—from a Cracker Jacks box?”* <sub>(Christopher Meeks, 2005)</sub>
- a comma: *“Where did you get your license, in some kind of government giveaway?”* <sub>(Michael Fox, 2000)</sub>
- dual questions: *“Where'd you get your license? A vending machine?”* <sub>(Shirley Jump, 2013)</sub>
- an ellipsis: *“Where did you get your license... in a Cracker Jack box!”* <sub>(Joseph Santiago, 2008)</sub>

Even though all of those could be found in published works, scrolling through the results, the comma seemed most prevalent, followed by dual questions.

> *It seems wrong to make it two independent sentences, both ending with question marks*

Really? You think so? That practice seems okay to me.

Answer (score 0):

You can say:

> Where did you get your license, *on* the back of a cereal box?

Comment: I considered that, but it's part of casual dialogue and the added 'on' doesn't feel true.

Comment: Indeed, the question seems to be: _How to punctuate with the preposition elided?_